# How to include documents as subdocuments in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a basic user collection that consists of document like so:

```
{
   user: 3949fj9fn9rjhfne93,
   name: "Jerry",
   country: 'au',
   friends: ['20fn39r4hf93', 'g9en3irhr934', '4i5henifuw92']
}
```

Each of those friends also has a document the same, along with there being a large collection of countries that can be queried via the country code.

```
{
   code: 'AU',
   name: 'Australia'
}, {
   code: 'NZ',
   name: 'New Zealand'
}
```

My question is, how would I include the full document for each of those array items within the result, like so:

```
{
   user: 3949fj9fn9rjhfne93,
   name: "Jerry",
   country: {
      code: 'AU',
      name: 'Australia'
   },
   friends: [{
       user: 20fn39r4hf93,
       name: "Bob",
       friends: ['2049429fr', 'djwij393i4']
   }, {
       user: g9en3irhr934,
       name: "Foo",
       friends: []
   }, {
       user: 4i5henifuw92,
       name: "Bar",
       friends: ['2049429fr']
   }]
}
```

I am using Mongoose in my application, and I understand that this could be done by using a simple `for` loop and pushing the results to the user object and then returning it in node with `res.json(user)`, although what if the user had hundreds (or even thousands) of friends? The request would be huge. I also need to do this in multiple places within my API.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked into `bulk update`?

Comment: @titi23 - I didn't think bulk update was a valid solution since it would add the friends to the user as an embedded document instead of referencing them. For example, what if one of the users changed their names? It would need to reference the up to date data, not old data.

Comment: May be [query.populate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) will help you? It's like JOIN from SQL

Comment: @MiKeBu - Looks like it's exactly what I'm after, thanks!